# SUMPRODUCT Stopped working with new versions of excel

Tags: excel, sumproduct

I have an issue with a function that so far functioned very well in a file that I have been having for many years now (my runs :) )
I need to average over a column only the values that correspond to a certain date range. This is what I used that so far has been working:

=(SUMPRODUCT((YEAR($B$3:$B$1603)=2020)*(MONTH($B$3:$B$1603)=2)*($E$3:$E$1603)))/SUMPRODUCT((YEAR($B$3:$B$1603)=2020)*(MONTH($B$3:$B$1603)=2)*($E$3:$E$1603<>""))

It takes all the values for For 2/2020 of column E and averages them
This maybe not sophisticated, but it used to work
Now, it works if there are no blank cells in the range. Otherwise gives a #value error.
Notice that if i do it ex novo in another sheet, it works perfectly even with blank cells! It as if with the new versions of excel the formula did not work
I am completely lost...
Thank you for your help!
Francesco

Comment: Don't you need something between the arguments such as `(YEAR($B$3:$B$1603)=2020)*(MONTH($B$3:$B$1603)=2)`?

Comment: Hi! It started working again when I reopened the file a few days later and I had done simply nothing!! I have no idea of what was wrong